# Different methods of using drawing rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Trying to learn javascript canvas, but having a difficult time figuring out which of these is preferred:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    context.stroke();
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    context.stroke();
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    context.stroke();
</script>
```

It seems to not matter which one I choose, two triangles will be drawn anyhoo. It is said that everytime beginPath() is called, the previous subpath made gets erased. But what about when to beginPaths are used, like in the last code snippet. Doesn't the last subpath need to be erased?

I guess that the concept of paths seems lost on me; everywhere I read that it's "like drawing with a pencil and then inking the lines". Great! But none seem to explain *why* this is. There's a strokeRect, why not just have a line that gets drawn immediately? Does it have to do with optimalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beginPath` resets the current path in the context, if you've made any settings/adding paths in the context, `beginPath` will reset them. In this example:

```
context.beginPath();
context.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
context.beginPath(); // Resets path
context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
context.stroke();
```

since you reset the path without calling `stroke`, you'll only get one rectangle. It has nothing to do with clearing the screen, just clearing whatever is in the memory of the context, so to speak.

http://jsbin.com/getejuxeva/edit

If you don't quite get what it's good for, compare these two:

http://jsbin.com/kojojofixa/1/edit

and

http://jsbin.com/gevacefumo/1/edit

Comment: Then what is it you don't understand? I thought this answered your question.

Comment: You thought wrong. It has to do with beginPath itself. I don't see why it is needed, since I can also show two rectangles without using beginPath. In fact, all three snippets I put up display two triangles. So, three different ways, same result. Why then beginPath? What is it good for?

Comment: I think I clarified my answer a bit. What it is good for is doing f.e exactly what's in my example. :)

Comment: What is f.e? Clearing the memory of the context seems to be going in the direction of the answer I was looking for. I mean, if it's not visible what it's doing, then it must be good for doing something else.What is the reason then of that something else. Because, if I know that, then I know when to apply it. Now I have no idea.

Comment: f.e = for example. Check my updated answer, I think the penny will drop :)